# Reshaping to all value combinations when unstacking a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, data-manipulation

### Background

I have a pandas DataFrame which serves as a register for key-values pairs `c` and `v` respective to a plan `p`:

```py
In [1]: a = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'p':[1, 1, 2],
   ...:     'c':['alpha', 'beta', 'alpha'],
   ...:     'v':['orange', 'football', 'apple']})

In [2]: a
Out[2]:
   p      c         v
0  1  alpha    orange
1  1   beta  football
2  2  alpha     apple
```

#### Method 1

The idea is that for every new line, I have another key-value pair that will later serve as the merging columns with another DataFrame. That way, by stacking and unstacking on the `v` column, I'll get the table in the desired shape for a join/merge operation:

```py
In [3]: a.set_index(['c', 'p']).stack().unstack(0).reset_index()
Out[3]:
c  p level_1   alpha      beta
0  1       v  orange  football
1  2       v   apple       NaN
```

#### Method 2

Now, in another case, I could have **different `v` values for the same `p` plan and `c` key**, which requires an additional step to avoid a `ValueError` for duplicate entries:

```py
In [4]: b = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'p':[3, 3, 4, 4],
   ...:     'c':['alpha', 'alpha', 'beta', 'beta'],
   ...:     'v':['orange', 'apple', 'football', 'rugby']})

In [5]: b['nid'] = b.groupby('c')['c'].cumcount()

In [6]: b.set_index(['c', 'nid', 'p']).stack().unstack(0).reset_index().sort_values('p')
Out[6]:
c  nid  p level_2   alpha      beta
0    0  3       v  orange       NaN
2    1  3       v   apple       NaN
1    0  4       v     NaN  football
3    1  4       v     NaN     rugby
```

---

### New implementation

I'm struggling however to come up with a method in this second example where I can have **different `v` values for different `c` values, for the same `p` plan**, and get a "dot" result, where all combinations of each key-value pairs show up in the final DataFrame.

```py
In [7]: pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'p':[5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6],
   ...:     'c':['alpha', 'alpha', 'beta', 'beta', 'gaga', 'gaga'],
   ...:     'v':['orange', 'apple', 'football', 'rugby', 'cake', 'pie']})
Out[7]:
   p      c         v
0  5  alpha    orange
1  5  alpha     apple
2  5   beta  football
3  5   beta     rugby
4  6   gaga      cake
5  6   gaga       pie
```

Using Method 2 would join the `c` keys along the same `p` and `nid` columns:

```
c  nid  p level_2   alpha      beta  gaga
0    0  5       v  orange  football   NaN
2    1  5       v   apple     rugby   NaN
1    0  6       v     NaN       NaN  cake
3    1  6       v     NaN       NaN   pie
```

However, the desired output should be something similar to:

```
   p   alpha      beta  gaga
0  5  orange  football   NaN
1  5  orange     rugby   NaN
2  5   apple  football   NaN
3  5   apple     rugby   NaN
4  6     NaN       NaN  cake
5  6     NaN       NaN   pie
```

To make it clearer:

- For `p == 5`, I have registered **2** values for `alpha`, **2** values for `beta`, thus I would need **2x2 = 4 pairs**;
- For `p == 6`, I have only registered **2** values for `gaga`, so in this case it would only replicate these 2 rows;
- Say that, for another `p == 7`, I register **2** values for `alpha`, **3** values for `beta` and **4** values for `gaga`, the output DataFrame would have **2x3x4 = 24 triplets** to account for all combinations.

Any ideas as to how can I accomplish this? It doesn't have to be in a single command, just in case.

---

### Edit

It might be accomplished with the use of `itertools.product` instead of creating the auxiliary `nid` column, but at the point of getting the combinations, I end up losing the reference to `c` so I'm unable to unstack:

```py
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({
    'p':[5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6],
    'c':['alpha', 'alpha', 'beta', 'beta', 'gaga', 'gaga'],
    'v':['orange', 'apple', 'football', 'rugby', 'cake', 'pie']})

xlist = x.groupby(['p', 'c'])['v'].apply(list)

xprod = xlist.groupby('p').apply(lambda g: list(product(*g)))
```

These lists will have the correct combinations for every different `p`, including ones with a single `c` (in the case of `xprod.loc[6]`), but at this point, reference to `c`'s name is lost:

```
p
5    [(orange, football), (orange, rugby), (apple, ...
6                                    [(cake,), (pie,)]
Name: v, dtype: object
```

Using `itertools` actually seems to be more efficient, but I'm stuck after this last step.

Comment: could you add some more explanation justifying the expected output.

Comment: @anky sure: as mentioned, these DFs are the basis for a join/merge operation with another DF containing actual values (let's call it `val`). So, in the last case, for `p == 5` I will eventually merge with `val` **on** `['alpha', 'beta']` and for `p == 6`, I'll merge **on** `'gaga'`. Therefore I need the "combinations" in the output. Using numbers for values wasn't the most clear, though, I'll update the question.

Comment: Updated, in the end it's a **combinatorics** problem coupled with data manipulation with pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `groupby` and `explode`:

```
df['nid'] = df.groupby('c')['c'].cumcount()
df.set_index(['c', 'nid', 'p']).stack().unstack(0).sort_values('p').groupby(level='p').agg(lambda x: list(set(x)))
for col in k.columns:
    k = k.explode(col)
```

OUTPUT:

```
c   alpha      beta  gaga
p                        
5  orange     rugby   NaN
5  orange  football   NaN
5   apple     rugby   NaN
5   apple  football   NaN
6     NaN       NaN   pie
6     NaN       NaN  cake
```

`NOTE`: Here, I've used `set` to aggregate you can use `list` if required.

Comment: SO didn't notify me of this answer, sorry for the late reply. I'm a bit confused here, though. `k` after the last statement will be shaped (2, 3), having `c` correctly displaying on the columns, but the rows will still show the `set` objects instead of exploding the DataFrame. I'm trying getting there with `itertools.product`, but at one point I lose my references to `c`, unfortunately.

Comment: I guess exploding every column 1 by 1 will yield the same answer. Anyways, I've updated my answer to be a little less complex. @manoelpqueiroz

Comment: I don't know if maybe it's a pandas versioning problem, but even with the updated answer, `set` objects are unable to explode and using `list` will generate a (256, 3) DataFrame O_O

Comment: If you're able to explode the list then you can just convert the set back to the list and explode. I've updated my answer